# phonegap app work fine in desktop but not in mobile

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap

I make a login page with angular
it seem like angular is not even loading in mobile i used a variable to test the angular is loaded or not in desktop browser it work but when i run it on my phone angular is not load and variable is not printing

```
$scope.test= 122;
```

Don't know the problem cause, i also test after building but still same problem.

the login page is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login </title>
    <link href="css/loginnew.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700|Lato:400,100,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">-->
    <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loginstyle.css">-->



    <style>



        .errorlabel
        {

            color: red;
            font-weight: normal;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.28);

        }

    </style>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="logincontroller">


<!--
    you can substitue the span of reauth email for a input with the email and
    include the remember me checkbox
    -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="card card-container">
        <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
        <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="img/user.jpg" />
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <form class="form-signin">
            <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
            <input id="name" ng-model="username" placeholder="     username" type="text" style="    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 17px;">
            {{test}}
            <input id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="     **********" type="password" style="    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 17px;">

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" ng-click="verifylogin(username , password)"> Login </button>
 <span class="errorlabel">{{errormessage}}</span>           
 <a href="#" class="forgot-password">
            Forgot the password?
        </a>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /card-container -->
</div><!-- /container -->


</body>



<script> function ajaxcall(rurl,rdata,successfunc,title,message)
 {
     alert('aese hi');
    rurl= "https://basit.co/"+rurl ;
    $.ajax({
        url: rurl, data:  rdata  ,
        success: function(data)
        {
            //unblur();
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            //data.data = JSON.parse(data.data);
            if(data.errors.length>0)
            {
                $.each(data.errors, function(ind,e){
                    console.log(" --"+e.message);
                    sweetw('Error', e.message);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if(successfunc)
                {
                    successfunc(data);
                    return;
                }
                if(rdata.reload)
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2500);
                }
                console.log();
                if(!title)
                {
                    sweets("Success",'');
                }else{
                    sweets(title,message);
                }

            }

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //   unblur();
            console.log(jqXHR);
            alert("Server Error");
        },
        type: 'POST' ,
    });
}</script>


<script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


    app.controller('logincontroller', function($scope) {

        $scope.loginuser="";
        $scope.errormessage = "";

        $scope.test= 122;
        $scope.verifylogin = function (username,password){

            ajaxcall("backend/accountf.php",{"verifylogin":true,username,password},function(response){

                    console.log(response.data);

                 if( username=="" || !username)
                    {
                         $scope.errormessage= response.data[0].errordetail;
                    }

                   else if(response.data[0].username == username)
                    {
                        $scope.loginuser = username ;
                        var currentpage = "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
                        location.href ='indextest.html';
                        $scope.errormessage="";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.errormessage= response.data[0].errordetail;
                        // alert(response.data[0].errordetail);
                    }
                    $scope.$digest();
                }
            );
        }

    });

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your angular module (myApp) in the code... Try calling the script containing your angular module.

Answer (score 0):

it work fine with android version greater then jellybean but not work with lower
so i send data with typescript format as `ajaxcall("backend/accountf.php",{"verifylogin":true,"username":username,"password":password},function(response){
.
.
.
}`

and now it work :)